# Unable to run JUnit test case in Hybris version 2101

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4, sap-commerce-cloud

Can anyone help me to resolve an issue of JUnit case in Hybris?

I have written a test case for DefaultWNMediaServiceTest class but getting an error while it is executing @Mock ModelService = modelService; statement.

Error is: Java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError and caused by java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (java.lang.String.byte[], int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @5e955596

Below is a class for it.

```
@UnitTest 
public class DefaultWNMediaServiceTest
{

@InjectMocks
DefaDefaultWNMediaService systemUnderTest = new DefaDefaultWNMediaService();

@Mock
ModelService modelService;

@Mock
MockHttpServletResponse response;

@Test
public void shouldThrowExceptionIfMediaPkIsNull(){
doThrow(NullPointerException.class).when(systemUnderTest).sendFile(null,response.getOutputStream());
}}
```

**Note:**

1. In local.properties.
   installed.tenants=junit,foo,t1,t2
2. In HAC.
   I activated Junit tenant and initialize the system (successfully finished).
3. I also checked that all the extensions are enable fora JUnit in HAC.

**Versions:**

1. JUnit Version is 4.13.1
2. Hybris Version is 2101
3. Mockito Core version is 1.10.19

Your help is much appreciated.!

Best.

Comment: how are you running test case like via ide or using ant target

Comment: I am using test case vie Spring Tool Suite and Compiler set as 1.8 Version of Java.

Comment: Hi as an alternative please try this.
ant unittests -Dtestclasses.suppress.junit.tenant=true -Dtest="Custom Class name with packagename"

Comment: I have done after your suggestion, now getting NotAMockException. Even though I have added @InjectMock on systemUnderTest class and above code is for reference.

Comment: I would suspect something with the runner. You could try to set the runner by annotating the class with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Comment: I also tried with @RunWith annotation but same error.

Answer (score 0):

I could find the solution of Java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError by applying two major changes in local system.

1. I also installed Java 11 version.
2. I changed compiler setting in eclipse from Java JDK 17 to Java 11 Version.
3. I downloaded new JRE 11 version and changed JRE setting in eclipse and specified newly JRE 11 version there.

But I still facing an issue of NotAMockException.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Mockito.dothrow().when() method tries to mock your testing class. This shouldn't be the case. Your class to be tested should be called in a normal fashion.
2. Your method name indicates that you want to assert the result of the method. This has to be done for exceptions in the Test() annotation.
3. Also the MockHttpServletResponse should be instantiated normally since it is already a mock implementation prepared for testing.

Have a look at this suggested implementation. It may have to be adjusted depending on your implementation of DefaultWNMediaService and if further classes have to be mocked.

```
@UnitTest
// Instantiate the mocked fields
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DefaultWNMediaServiceTest
{

    @InjectMocks
    DefaDefaultWNMediaService systemUnderTest;

    @Mock
    ModelService modelService;

    // Assert the excepetion in the method header
    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void shouldThrowExceptionIfMediaPkIsNull()
    {
        // Don't construct this with @Mock since the object is already a mocked implementation
        MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

        // Run instance without mocking it
        systemUnderTest.sendFile(null, response.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```